# Facebook Messenger webhook POST repeatedly sending the same text

Tags: spring, facebook-chatbot

I created a facebook messenger chatbot app. The problem is webhook does not stop sending the same text, so its answering a lot of times for the same question. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hi Alvaro, we will definitely need more information from you to help. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us some code near where you suspect the problem is occurring.

Comment: My bad                   ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my server, which took more than 30 seconds to respond to that webhook request. The solution was send first a 200 OK response to facebook and then process the text, get the response and send it to facebook user's chat.